Command "ping" is not found Discord.py 2.0
Every time I try to connect Cogs I get an error
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not found
main
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members=True
token = "token"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents, help_command=None)


async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

async def main():
    await load()
    await bot.start("token")

bot.run("token")

cogs
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("bot Is Online")

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("pong")


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(ping(bot))

I tried to do load and unload but these commands didn’t help either

Be aware that anyone with your bot token can do malicious things, so do not publish it online. Sending it here probably triggered discord mechanism and your token was reset. (If not, I published it in a github gist since Discord will automatically reset any token published there)

Reset your token.
You're not actually loading any cogs, as you're starting the bot via Bot.run, you need to call your main() function to start the bot with extension loading.
Replace your bot.run() with asyncio.run(main()).
